# Store command result in string doesn't always work

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a command line program with Rust and I will the need the program to be able to store the result of commands in strings

Here is the current program ([source](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-command-in-rust/45633)):

```rust
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("ls")
        // Tell the OS to record the command's output
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        // execute the command, wait for it to complete, then capture the output
        .output()
        // Blow up if the OS was unable to start the program
        .unwrap();

    // extract the raw bytes that we captured and interpret them as a string
    let stdout = String::from_utf8(output.stdout).unwrap();

    println!("{}", stdout);
}
```

This program works on some commands for example `ls` but others don't. For example if I try with `ll` or `git branch` (which is an example of what I'd like to achieve btw) I have this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/main.rs:10:10
```

Why does this happen and how can I correct it? My environment is Linux.

Comment: did you try the commands on your computer? because the error looks clear `Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }`

Comment: These exemples do work `ll` and `git branch` when I execute them directly in the terminal

Comment: `"ll"` is not a command, it is a common shell alias for the `ls` command with `-l` as argument. `"git branch"` is not a command either (when you type it in an interactive shell, the command is `git` and `branch` is a parameter).

Comment: Yeah for `git branch` you'd need `Command::new("git").arg("branch")`

Comment: Awesome this is it ! Thanks a lot, I didn't thought of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for `git branch` (for example) is:

```rust
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("git").arg("branch")
        // Tell the OS to record the command's output
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        // execute the command, wait for it to complete, then capture the output
        .output()
        // Blow up if the OS was unable to start the program
        .unwrap();

    // extract the raw bytes that we captured and interpret them as a string
    let stdout = String::from_utf8(output.stdout).unwrap();

    println!("{}", stdout);
}
```